# PowerShell 5 class handling in older versions

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to search solutions on this one, but I'm coming up blank. I have a small dilemma with a script I've written for PowerShell 5 or higher as it's using classes for it's functionality.

I had added the following to the start of the script hoping it would bail out gracefully on older versions and throw an exit code I can use

```
If ($((Get-Host).Version.Major) -lt 5)
{
    $host.UI.WriteErrorLine('PowerShell Version 5 is required.')
    [Environment]::Exit(12345)
}
```

However, it seems my intended purpose of the above fails because older versions of PowerShell seem to read the whole script and throw the following because it can't interpret the class.

```
class : The 'class' keyword is not supported in this version of the language.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ReservedKeywordNotAllowed
```

Outside of writing a second sort of a wrapper script to handle checking the PowerShell version and then execute the script I've written, is anyone aware of any way to handle this within the single script?

Comment: Have you tried `#Requires -Version 5` ? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: `#Requires` is the way to go.  On other occasions you may need to look at the version # you can use `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major`.

Comment: Ah yes that's it. I knew I was overlooking something simple. Thanks gents